# GWT Bootstrap3 creating Custom Cell for DataGrid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, events, gwt, datagrid, custom-cell

I am struggeling getting a custom cell in bootstrap3 format to work in a datagrid.
I failed on formatting and getting the events.
In this case I was able to get the proper "Bootstrap 3 Input Cell" in my table, having the nice bootstrap3 look & feel, however I cannot get events and also the cssBuilder code did not work.

```
Column<TableData, SafeHtml> col1 = new Column<TableData, SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell()) {
            @Override
            public SafeHtml getValue(TableData object) {               
               SafeStylesBuilder cssBuilder = new SafeStylesBuilder();              
               SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();  
               cssBuilder.appendTrustedString("margin-top: 5px;");
               Input i1= new Input();
               
               sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(i1.toString()));                           
               return templates.cell(cssBuilder.toSafeStyles(), sb.toSafeHtml());
            }               
        };
```

As I tried so many different variants (and failed) I am desperate for real application code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used the bootstrap grid system to make up a custom grid

```
/**
 * Addiere eine Zeile zum Panel dazu
 * @param column
 */
void addToPanel(Column [] column,int iIndex) {
    Row row=new Row();          
    int iIt;
    for (iIt=0;iIt<column.length;iIt++) {
        row.add(column[iIt]);
    }
    panelbody.insert(row,iIndex);   
}
```

Within each column element you can put in typical elements like Text, Input, CheckBox, ListBox, etc ... You can override those elements in order to link to the underlying data resources ..

```
    class MInput extends Input implements SetGet{
    RowData rData;
    int iColumn;
    MInput mI;
    
    public MInput (int iColumn, RowData rData) {
        super();
        mI=this;
        this.rData=rData;
        this.iColumn=iColumn;
        this.addBlurHandler(
            new BlurHandler () {
                @Override
                public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    rData.saData[iColumn]=mI.getText();                     
                }               
        });
        this.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {   
                if ( event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER ) {
                    mI.setFocus(false);
                }                   
            }               
        });
    }
    
    public String get() {           
        return rData.saData[iColumn];
    }
    
    public void set(String strSet) {
        this.setText(strSet);
        rData.saData[iColumn]=strSet;
    }
}
```

SetGet is a class just to have a general access to each columndata element.